# DB2 error in using the cursor in PL/SQL function

Tags: cursor, db2

I am declaring a cursor in DB2 PL/SQL function as below:

```
create function query1(tbname VARCHAR(32), msisdn VARCHAR(32)) 
returns VARCHAR(40) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
READS SQL DATA 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
DETERMINISTIC 
begin atomic 
    DECLARE vsql varchar(2000); 
    DECLARE dt_UTC   date; 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR select productid from Subscription_000 where msisdn= 123456; 
    SET vsql = 'select productid from Subscription_000 where msisdn= 123456'; 
OPEN C1; 


    return '123'; 
end 
@
```

I saved the above contents to k2.sql and
When I try to compile this function using the command: db2 -td@ -f k2.sql I am getting the below error:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned:  SQL0104N  An unexpected token "FOR" was found following
>   "DECLARE C1 CURSOR".  Expected tokens may include: 
>   "".  LINE  NUMBER=10. 
>   SQLSTATE=42601

Any suggestions on What is the problem here...?

Answer (score 3):

This was a tricky one, but after some testing I figured out the problem: you can't declare a cursor within an atomic compound statement.  Replace `BEGIN ATOMIC` with just `BEGIN`.

I wish I could point you to the list of allowed statements for `ATOMIC`, but it is buried in the manual somewhere and I can't find it at the moment.

(This is a classic case of DB2's terrible error reporting.  Shouldn't it be able to recognize a disallowed statement and tell you that?)

*Edit: this is one of the problems, but there is also some other problem, which I am not having, so I can't debug it.*

Comment: I replaced BEGIN ATOMIC with just BEGIN, but now I am getting different error:DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned: 
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "begin" was found following "CTION DETERMINISTIC 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<labeled_begin_atomic>".  LINE NUMBER=7. 
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: It compiled fine for me when I sent the function via an SQL editor.  It sounds like an additional problem with running this from the command line.  Sorry, I can't help with that because I don't have access to the tool  (Or, I suppose it could be a version issue.  I am on DB2 LUW 9.7).

Comment: @Sekhar, from what I can tell in the manual, you may not be able to do this with a function in your version.  Depending on how you want to use it, you may want to write it as a procedure instead.